# Dimensions of matrix derivative and chain rule

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

I'm trying to calculate the derivative of the next expression with respect to matrix square $X$:
$$
\frac{∂ a^T(A - X)^{-1}b}{∂ X}
$$

where $A$ is constant square matrix, $a$ and $b$ are vectors. Since the top-level expression is scalar the derivative should have matrix form. However, when I apply the chain rule I get:
$$
ab^T \frac{∂(A-X)^{-1}}{∂X} = ab^T (A-X)^{-2} \frac{∂(A-X)}{∂X}
$$

There should be definitely a mistake because $\frac{∂(A-X)}{∂X}$ is matrix-by-matrix derivative and hence is more than 2-dimensional object. I suspect that I misunderstand how chain rule works for matrices, but can not find a mistake.

Comment: @ sbos, read a book about differential calculus. frank calculates $\nabla (f)(X)$, the gradient of $f$, that is a $n\times n$ matrix. jiboulet calculates $Df_X$, the derivative of $f$, that is a linear application from $M_n$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Both answers are correct. The 2 above notions are linked by $<\nabla(f)(X),H>=tr((\nabla(f)(X))^TH)=Df_X(H)$.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than the chain rule, use differentials for this sort of problem.

For convenience, define a new variable 
$$\eqalign{
 M &= A-X \cr
dM &= -dX \cr
}$$
Express the function in terms of the [Frobenius (:) Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) and find its differential
$$\eqalign{
 f &= M^{-1}:ab^T \cr\cr
df &= dM^{-1}:ab^T \cr
   &=-M^{-1}\,dM\,M^{-1}:ab^T \cr
   &= M^{-1}\,dX\,M^{-1}:ab^T \cr
   &= M^{-T}ab^TM^{-T}:dX \cr
}$$
Since $df=\big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}:dX\big),\,$ the gradient must be
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= M^{-T}ab^TM^{-T} \cr
 &= (A^T-X^T)^{-1}ab^T(A^T-X^T)^{-1} \cr
}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the differential of $\mathrm{Inv} \, : \, A \in \mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{R}) \, \longmapsto \, A^{-1}$. One can prove that the differential of the inversion is given by :

$$ \mathrm{D}_{A} \mathrm{Inv} \cdot H = - A^{-1} H A^{-1} $$

So, using the chain rule, you get :

$$ \mathrm{D}_{X} (A-X)^{-1} \cdot H = \mathrm{D}_{A-X} (A-X)^{-1} \cdot (-H) = (A-X)^{-1} H (A-X)^{-1}$$

Now, consider the linear mapping $Y \, \longmapsto \, {}^t a Y b$ and apply the chain rule again. It gives :

> $$ \mathrm{D}_{X} (A-X)^{-1} \cdot H = {}^t a (A-X)^{-1} H (A-X)^{-1} b $$

Comment: I'm a bit confused by notation. What is $D_A Inv \cdot A$? And what is matrix $H$?

Comment: $\mathrm{D}_{A} \mathrm{Inv}$ generalises the notion of derivative for applications defined on an open set of a normed linear space (here, $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is an open set of $\mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$. $\mathrm{D}_{A} \mathrm{Inv} \cdot H$ is the value at point $H$ of the linear application $\mathrm{D}_{A} \mathrm{Inv}$, which is the differential at point $A$ of $\mathrm{Inv}$.